# How to retrieve the best given name of a User in Android?

Tags: android, contactscontract

I retrieve the display name of a user via the [ContactsContract API](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html) in Android.

Now I want to retrieve the given(first) name of this user. There are specific [Rows](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.html) in the [data](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Data.html) table that contain the name of the user. The problem is that there are multiple rows for every user because of the synchronization and aggregation of contacts.

The Contacts table [documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Contacts.html) states that there should be column containing the id of the raw contact that contributes the primary name for this user. But there is no constant name for this column defined and I couldn't find this column inside my data table.

How do I retrieve the Id of the raw contact that contributes the DisplayName to a contact?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the "[IS_PRIMARY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#IS_PRIMARY)" or the "[IS_SUPER_PRIMARY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.DataColumns.html#IS_SUPER_PRIMARY)" flag in the [RawContactsEntity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.RawContactsEntity.html)-table may solve your problem.